# Entry to CIA Part #1

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, cipher, story, science

As I searched for different topics on Google, my whole screen suddenly went black and gave me this letter:

> Dear Reader,
> if you have come across this message, you may be applicable for the CIA.
> We are looking for some of the best mathematicians in the world. We think you might be one. To confirm your skills, we require that you decode this message:
> **30 265 75 5 340 . (d) (e) 135 40 (d) (e) = (t) 220 (e)**. Only the best mathematicians are able to decode this. If you can solve it, write back to us, and we will proceed with the next steps.

NOTE: The period and equals sign are included in the final message; they don't have anything to do with the decoding.

Hint 1:

> Divide all numbers by something that they are all divisible by.

Hint 2 (use after 1):

> Use PT to change the numbers into one letter or two letters.

Hint 3 (use after 2):

> Combine all the letters to form one string!

NOTE: The back story is fictional.

Next Part: [Part #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116446/).

Comment: Not that it matters, but wouldn't this be more of a CIA thing than a Secret Service thing?  CIA are the code breakers.  Secret Service are mostly just the protection detail for high level officials.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You're probably right! I didn't think much about that. I can change it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cipher (despite the CIA's claims) actually has little to do with mathematics, and much more to do with...

> **chemistry**.

First:

> Divide each number by 5, the common divisor of all numbers in the ciphertext:
>
>  6 53 15 1 68 . d e 27 8 d e = t 44 e

That's the mathematics part over with. Then:

> Replace each number with the Periodic Table symbol that corresponds to these *atomic numbers*:
>
>  C I P H Er . d e Co O d e = t Ru e

The result is:

> programming-like syntax saying **CIPHEr.deCoOde = tRue**, implying that the cipher has been successfully decoded (or is that 'decooded'?! After all,  it seems there is an extra 'O' in the plaintext output...).

Comment: Nice job! That's correct.