# Entry to CIA Part #2

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, cipher, story

Previous Part: [Part #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116431/)

After successfully completing Part #1's puzzle, you receive another message from the CIA on your black screen:

> Dear Reader, we are glad to state that you have been accepted into part #2 of the CIA admission challenge! Only the best mathematicians, scientists, and code crackers in the world are accepted. For the next puzzle we require you to use the **nfpvv_gnoyr** to decode **{ q w " u q n x g f " k v**.

You are required to solve **nfpvv_gnoyr**, then use the answer to solve **{ q w " u q n x g f " k v**.

NOTE: The hints are to be used in order.

Hint(s) for **nfpvv_gnoyr**:

Hint 1:

> r13

Hint(s) for **{ q w " u q n x g f " k v**:

Hint 1:

> Use the nfpvv_gnoyr, as mentioned before.

Hint 2:

> Use b10 number for each char.

NOTE: The back story is fictional.

Next Part: [Part #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116461/)

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what standard procedure / etiquette is around here, but I'd suggest not including the hints unless/until it seems they might be needed. The hints you provided aren't even really hints, they're just step-by-step instructions for solving the puzzle, which kinda takes some of the fun out of it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your feedback! I will edit my post and include this in my next puzzles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

> First we apply ROT13 to “nfpvv_gnoyr” which gives us “ascii_table.”
>
> Then, looking up the characters from { q w " u q n x g f " k v in the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/), we get the following numbers:
>
> 123 113 119 34 117 113 110 120 103 102 34 107 118
>
> Assuming the two instances of 34 should just be blanks suggests we might want to subtract 34 from all of the numbers. If we do that, we get the following:
>
> 89 79 85 0 83 79 76 86 69 68 0 73 84
>
> Looking up these new numbers on the ASCII table, they spell out:
>
> **YOU SOLVED IT**