# Entry to CIA Part #3

Tags: cipher

Previous Part: [Part #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116446/).

Your screen shifts, bringing a new message on. It is simple:

> There is one final challenge that must be solved before admission. If this is solved the CIA will accept you! Good luck.

Cipher:

**53 54 55 55 13 42 33 22**

**34 44 11 44 51 23 51 33 44**

Hint 1:

> Pay attention to the digits, rather than the numbers.

Hint 2:

> Use a table.

NOTE: Back story is fictional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just

> PUZZLING STATEMENT in [tap code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code).